Delete trailing whitespace on save, but only for yaml files
I would like to run delete-trailing-whitespace for files with extension .yaml only. Can someone please supply the elisp to do this?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

(add-hook 'yaml-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'before-save-hook
                      #'delete-trailing-whitespace
                      nil "local")))

